# Sorting Implementation - Array element is present but returns -1

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, indexof

I am working on implementing my own QuickSort method, but I am having trouble returning the index where first and last occur in my partition method. I've debugged the code line by line, and this shows.....
[image]

It is clear that the elements are present in the array, yet the index always return -1, suggesting they do not exist in the array.

Here is what my code looks like...can you tell why this might occur?

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Quicksort {

public static void sort(int[] arr) {
    int first = arr[0];
    int last = arr[arr.length - 1];
    quickSort(arr, first, last);
}

private static void quickSort(int[] arr, int first, int last) {
    if (first < last) {
        int pivot = partition(arr, first, last);
        quickSort(arr, first, pivot - 1);
        quickSort(arr, pivot + 1, last);
    }
}

private static int partition(int[] arr, int first, int last) {
    int pivot = first;
    int up = Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf(first);
    int down = Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf(last);
    System.out.println(up);
    System.out.println(down);

    do {
        if (arr[up] < pivot || arr[up] != last) {
            up++;
        }
        if (arr[down] > pivot || arr[down] != first) {
            down--;
        }
        if (up > down) {
            int temp = arr[up];
            arr[up] = arr[down];
            arr[down] = temp;
        }
    } while (up < down);

    int temp = arr[down];
    int pivotIndex = java.util.Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf(pivot);
    arr[down] = arr[pivotIndex];
    arr[pivotIndex] = temp;
    return pivot;
}

public static void printArr(int[] arr) {
    System.out.println(IntStream.of(arr)
            .boxed()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {5, 14, 30, 2, 40, 14};
    printArr(arr);
    sort(arr);
    printArr(arr);

}
}
```

Comment: What did you discover when you debugged this?

Comment: The picture of my debugging is in the post. You can see the element in the array, but it return -1

Comment: How can `up` or `down` have values at this point?  Your breakpoint appears to be before these are even declared.

Comment: I set the breakpoint there, but stepped over the next two lines so I could see the values from the IntelliJ debugger and then captured the image

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).size());`

Comment: So I see now that my array is actually of size 0 when I print it out.

Answer (score 0):

The signature to `Arrays.asList` expects either a varargs of objects, or an array of objects.  An `int[]` is not an array of objects, and Java does not autobox it to `Integer[]`.  Thus it is treated as a vararg, and you thus get a `List<int[]>`.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't even aware of the fact that Java doesn't autobox. Is there a way to convert an int[] array to an Integer[] array so I could run my indexOf on the newly created array, yet apply the result to my original array?

Comment: To clarify, Java autoboxes primitive types.  It does not autobox arrays.  There is nothing in core Java which provides the ability to do this, but if your course allows, you can convert it using a library provided by [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toObject(byte[])).